# Modificar variable en un campo de texto al activar caslla con chekbox con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Tengo un campo de texto con un valor asignado a una variable en php. Deseo que al activar una checkbox me permita modificar tal valor, al momento de pasarlo con un POST al otro formulario no me muestra los datos que he ingresado manualmente en el type text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
        <title>FORMULARIO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
            <?php
                $nombre_completo="Pablo";
                $jefe_inmediato="prueba@ggs.mx";
            ?>
            <body>
                <div class="form-bottom">
                    <form role="form" class="login-form" action="verificar.php" method="POST" id="login-form">
                        <div class="form-group hidden">
                            <div class="alert alert-warning fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign alert-icon "></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre_solicitante"class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label">Nombre del Solicitante  </label>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="nombre_solicitante" name="nombre_completo" placeholder="<?php echo $nombre_completo; ?>" class="form-control" disabled></div>
                            <label for="jefe_inmediato"class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label">Jefe Inmediato </label>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="jefe_inmediato" name="jefe_inmediato" value="<?php echo $jefe_inmediato; ?>" class ="form-control" disabled></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-check-input" id="chk" type="checkbox" name="" value="" />Activa la casilla si el correo de jefe inmediato es incorrecto es incorrecto y escribelo</label></div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            var button = $('#jefe_inmediato');
                            $('#chk').change(function(event) {
                                if ($(event.target).is(':checked')) {
                                    button.removeAttr('disabled');
                                } else {
                                    button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                }
                            });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn-formulario" name="enviar" value="enviar" >Aceptar</button>
                    <?php
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" hidden=\"hidden\" value='".$jefe_inmediato."' name=\"jefe_inmediato\">";
                    ?>
                </form>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn-cancelar" name="cancelar" value="cancelar" >Cancelar</button>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("btn-cancelar").onclick = function () {
                    location.href = "index.php";
                };
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
        <title>VERIFICAR LOS DATOS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-lg-10 form-box"><!--Ancho de la pagina -->
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <form role="form" class="login-form" method="POST" id="login-form" action="enviar.php">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">¿No son correctos los datos? <a href="index.php" target=""><p class="text-danger"> Cancela e ingresa de nuevo los datos</p></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Solicitud a </button> <?php echo '<h4>' .$_POST['jefe_inmediato'].'</h4>';?>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Antes de Activar casilla para cambiar correo]
[image: Activo la casilla y le coloco un correo electronico diferente]
[image: Al dar click en enviar no me muestra el correo que agrege, sino me pone el por defecto que declare al inicio del codigo]

Comment: Que version de jquey usas? lo probe en 2.1.1 y funciona bien. Si acaso ese es el problema... entonces, cual es el problema concreto?

Comment: Mi version es 1.11 sin embargo al previsualizar los datos en el otro formulario me coloca el valor de id que ya tenia el type text. Es decir al colocar un valor no me hace los cambios, me sigue colocando lo que ya trae por default el typetext. Necesito ayuda para que con JavaScript pueda reemplazar el valor de $jefe_inmediato por un nuevo valor. Gracias.

Comment: OK, con 1.11 no funciona, pues no tiene `porp`, pero $jefe_inmediato esta en PHP, osea del lado del servidor. Para cambiarlo deberas permitir que se cambie en el HTML y luego enviar el form.

Comment: Estas seguro de que necesitas usar **placeholder** (atributo que muestra un msj cuando el input esta vacio) en lugar de **value** (atributo para especificar el valor del elemento)?

Comment: Tienes razón Marcos, el atributo placeholder es innecesario, utilice value para mostrar el valor que tiene asignado el typetext. Gracias. ahora solo queda que si activo la casilla me permita reemplazar el valor que tiene la variable $jefe_inmediato por un nuevo valor escribiendo directamente en ese typetext

Comment: @JuanPabloBustamanteLuna NO puedes actualizar la variable PHP desde javascript sin enviar el form, esto es algo diferente que tienes que hacer en PHP cuando recibes el formulario de vuelta (osea cuando el usuario envia el Submit)

Comment: Que extraño, pense que directamente si el correo es incorrecto, podia activar con un ckeck y escribir un nuevo dato y enviarlo y visualizar en el otro form

Comment: Alguna ayuda de favor